# Facebook OAuth2 dialog opening in a new tab instead of popup window with (Sinatra, Ruby, OAuth2)

Tags: javascript, ruby, facebook, oauth, sinatra

I've noticed that on a bunch of websites, when a user is prompted to connect with facebook, everything is happens on a new "popup window". I've started to play with the OAuth2 gem and Sinatra and when I copy/paste the code from this example https://github.com/intridea/oauth2, the user authentication/authorization happens in a new browser tab instead of a cute little popup window.

What am I doing wrong?
How Am I supposed to do it?
Do I absolutely need to use the Facebook JS SDK?

thx

LP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Official Facebook Javascript SDK to do the login:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

That's much easier and provides the unified UI experience (which is the popup window you are looking for).

Comment: Great but once it is done, how do I get the access_token to make api calls on behalf of the user??

Comment: access_token will be stored in cookie by Javascript; your server will get the cookie with HTTP requests following the complete login (be sure to verify it against sha1 hash and your app secret token)

Answer (score 0):

You must read this http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook it's working just fine here.